# Перевод публичного ключа в алгоритме Диффи-Хеллмана на android из byte[] в String и обратно в byte[]

Tags: алгоритм, криптография, шифрование

Здравствуйте, я реализую алгоритм Диффи-Хеллмана между двумя устройствами с помощью Bluetooth. Между телефонами уже установлена Bluetooth связь, и есть возможность обмениваться сообщениями в моем приложении-чате. Схема такая:

1. При нажатии на главном телефоне кнопки шифрование, телефон генерирует пару ключей, открытый ключ передает в TextInputEditText, предварительно преобразовав его из byte[] в String, а затем данное сообщение передается на второй телефон, иными словами, открытый ключ передается как простое сообщение чата.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. На втором устройстве, путем нажатия на сообщение в ListView, мы выбираем пришедший открытый ключ и уже на основе этого ключа генерируем свою пару ключей.

Но есть проблема, если публичный ключ проходит через преобразования вида .toString.getBytes() то он теряет свою спецификацию. Возможно ли как-то на приемной стороне восстановить публичный ключ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, можно видеть, что публичный ключ, что в формате строки, что в формате массива байтов, свое значение не изменяет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

`byte[]` в `String` не гарантирует однозначность трансляции, вам надо `byte[]` переводить в строку через `Base64` и обратно `Base64` в `byte[]` - он гарантирует однозначность трансляции.